# Helper library "select2" does not work for me

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-select2

## My Story

I'm about to provide a sample, so I can get a job. The employees of the company liked the way I write programming code, but since I wasn't the kind of person to work over a web page, they requested a well-designed one page sample code using [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 3 or 4, and they said I can use templates and helper tools, and the design is more important than that I complete it with my knowledge of HTML and CSS (though I have no knowledge of [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)), so I asked them for one week time, and I have made some part of it already, but there is work to do, and mostly it is the UI.

## Get To Work

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 (the [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) view engine), [Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), and select2, I'm not sure if my hierarchy is well-formed and affect the helper, but this is how I did it:

[image: ASP.NET MVC3 Hierarchy With Bootstrap and Select2]

So, I also add my connection like below in the `_layout.cshtml` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>

    <!--Select2-->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/select2-3.4.5/select2.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/select2-3.4.5/select2.js")"></script>

    <!--MY CSS-->
    <link href="~/Content/my_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

And then I went to my index File and added the following:

```
@model SinglePage.Models.SinglePageIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/select2-3.4.5/select2.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/select2-3.4.5/select2.js")"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#e1").select2(); });
</script>

<h2>خانه</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <select id="e1">
        @foreach (var customer in Model.CustomerList)
        {
            <option value="@Html.DisplayFor(c=>customer.Code)">@Html.DisplayFor(c => customer.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(c=>customer.LastName)</option>
        }
    </select>

}
```

It was like what the example told me. So I filled my select with data from SQL Server, and it became like this:

[image: Select Select2 Helper Won't Work]

So as you can see, it didn't affect the UI. I also checked the CSS and JavaScript link, but they didn't seem to be broken.

Also, I got some messages in my console, which I let you see in here:

[image: Console Logs for Select2 Helper Class]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: i repeat css and js linking just for test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console it shows `on` is not a function in `select2`, because you have an older version of [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). Update jQuery to the latest version. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. So you need to add the jQuery version 1.7 or later.

Comment: there is total library within MVC 3 beside jquery, i hope it dont hurt it...Thank you man